# Given the trigonometric equation relationship, how can I find the trigonometric function value of a certain combination angle?

Tags: equation-solving

The known conditions are as follows:

```
Sin[α + β] + Cos[α + β] == 2 Sqrt[2] Cos[α + π/4] Sin[β]
```

Request to find:

```
Tan[α - β]


Solve[{Sin[α + β] + Cos[α + β] == 2 Sqrt[2] Cos[α + π/4] Sin[β], 
   tan (α - β) == Sin[α - β]/Cos[α - β]}, 
  tan (α - β), {Sin[α - β], Cos[α - β]}] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: fixed your Greek. btw, you used lower case `tan`, it should be Uppercase `Tan` in the last Solve command.  Will leave that for you to fix. And you also used `( )` in place of `[ ]` there.

Comment: It is lowercase. I am taking tan and the angle behind it as a whole variable to find it.

Comment: ```Solve[TrigFactor[
  SubtractSides[
   Sin[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]] + Cos[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 
    2 Sqrt[2] Cos[\[Alpha] + \[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Beta]]]], 
 Tan[\[Alpha] - \[Beta]]]```This operation cannot be solved, and the result is displayed as an empty set

Comment: ``` tan (α - β)```I defined this whole as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assum = Sin[α + β] + Cos[α + β] == 2 Sqrt[2] Cos[α + π/4] Sin[β] // FullSimplify
(* Cos[α - β] + Sin[α - β] == 0 *)

FullSimplify[Tan[α - β] // TrigToExp, assum, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
(* -1 *)
```